# How to view data of particular point(s) in a scatterplot in Matplotlib?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot

I am using the following snippet of code to make a scatterplot using seaborn:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
plt.figure(figsize = (15,7))
sns.set()
plt.figure(figsize = (15,7))
sns.scatterplot(data  =  analysis_df, x = 'nota_percoftotal', y = 'post-pre')
plt.show()
```

This is the figure that I get:
[image]

As you can see, there is a stream of data points lying on the downwards sloping line. My question is, how can I know what these data points are in my dataset? My dataset looks something like this:

```
uni_const_code  nota_percoftotal     post-pre   
1|9|95          34.337349           -15.637197    
1|9|96          43.684211           -52.935894    
1|9|97          42.857143           -14.455647
```

The column `uni_const_code` is the key in the dataset.

Edit 1: I used mplcursors making the following modifications:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
x = analysis_df['nota_percoftotal'] 
y = analysis_df['post-pre'] 
line, = ax.plot(x, y, "to") 
mplcursors.cursor(ax).connect("add", lambda sel: sel.annotation.set_text(labels[sel.target.index]))
plt.show()
```

But I still don't get what I want. The output is just a scattergram like before, I don't get anything even when I hover/click on the scatter dots.

Comment: [mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) could be very helpful here. [This example](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/labeled_points.html) can be easily adapted, using `list(analysis_df['uni_const_code'])` as `labels`.

Comment: This is my new code: ```labels = list(analysis_df['uni_const_code'])```     
```fig, ax = plt.subplots()```
```x = analysis_df['nota_percoftotal']```   
```y = analysis_df['post-pre']```   
```line, = ax.plot(x, y, "ro")```
```mplcursors.cursor(ax).connect(
    "add", lambda sel: sel.annotation.set_text(labels[sel.target.index]))```
```plt.show()``` But I still don't get what I want. The output is just a scattergram like before. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question post to add the code. If you call `mplcursors.cursor(ax, hover=True)` you see the labels while hovering with the mouse. Without `hover` you need to click on a point of interest.

Comment: Even when I set the ```hover=True```, I still don't see any change. In fact, I downloaded the .ipynb file from the example you cited but even the example did not run as you mention it just returns me a scatter diagram.

Comment: Noted. For some reason, it does not work in Jupyter lab, even after adding ```%matplotlib nbagg``` but works perfectly on the terminal (without the aforementioned addition). Thank you. If you answer the question, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: It seems you need to add %matplotlib nbagg to run an interactive matplotlib image in Jupyter. (as mentioned [here](https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor/issues/48))